# How to split using date not using IP address

Tags: php

I have a large string having dates, Ip addresses etc.. I need to split the content with date and did that with

```
[0-9]+[/.-])([0-9]+[/.-][0-9]+
```

But it also split using the IP addresses. 
What the only difference between date and IP address is date have 3 numbers and Ip have 4 numbers like 28.06.2012 and 178.15.16.314. How can I omit the IP address from splitting the content?

Sorry. One more thing i forgot to add. That is there are other possibilities for the format of date like 25-06-12, 2012-06-25, 12-06-25.

Comment: try ([0-9]{2,4}[\.-]?){3} for dates

Comment: Could you show us an example of your string? Where are you getting it from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What the only difference between date and IP address is date have 3 numbers and Ip have 4 numbers like 28.06.2012 and 178.15.16.314. How can I omit the IP address from splitting the content?

First of all, the dates have *four* numbers representing the year. Second, an IP address has four octets. So the following should do the trick (not tested):

```
'~(\d{1,2}[.-]\d{1,2}[.-]\d{4})~'
```

Tested:

```
<?php
$date = '28.12.2012';
$ip = '192.168.0.1';

$regex = '~(\d{1,2}[.-]\d{1,2}[.-]\d{4})~';

var_dump( preg_match( $regex, $date ) ); // int(1)
var_dump( preg_match( $regex, $ip ) ); // int(0)
```

Comment: You don't need to escape `.` inside `[` character groups `]`.